# Is WASP-12 a F-type star or a G-type star?

Tags: star, spectral-type

I saw in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WASP-12) that WASP-12 is a star with spectral type of G0V while they said its temperature is 6360 K. Does that mean it must be a star with spectral type of F7V or F6V? Its size is not like a normal G-type star should have.

Comment: Basing his analysis on the Gaia, PARSEC and PASTEL catalogues, Valeri Makarov arrived at the values Teff = 6310 K, age = 2.08 Gyr, and M = 1.36 M_{sun}, see https://www.mdpi.com/2218-1997/8/4/211  For details, you may want to write to Valeri directly, using his e-mail shown there. He may be able to help.

Comment: Use proper punctuation and pay attention to capitalization.

Answer (score 5):

There is actual variation in the literature.

The [WASP team announcement of the discovery of a planet](http://simbad.cds.unistra.fr/simbad/sim-ref?bibcode=2009ApJ...693.1920H) states "the host star is a supersolar metallicity ([M/H] = 0.3+0.05–0.15), late-F (Teff= 6300+200–100 K) star which is evolving off the zero-age main sequence."

Simbad, which is a "catalog of catalogues" lists the star as G0V, and cites Bergfors et.al. "[Stellar companions to exoplanet host stars](https://watermark.silverchair.com/182.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAsAwggK8BgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggKtMIICqQIBADCCAqIGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMWknWfwObZqxIV-YrAgEQgIICc5UWJdisrTPtFQ_PQwfP9NwsbQAXOsnJLHWu1VrIApXVyJs4FJRhIMloSiNfO9MzEVhz2C9-46fC4KA3Oncasto0c6mYg5kLnrNzdJCPxgMuFbW8znb2mcj7O-zepuyO636sVaVX8OiLHNuOCOOpUbLMImiuzuaLQLTawD-SlAsa15DpkwR5sdEFmWxF9umFZDeMLH-UdJcUXEdDeT9r-4B1r-rxClxtYbRCUxP21EHL8zCegPj8GEdCnGzHirT5gIwIk2MpZKCroW1zl4VfEIlgRNp6FCnA2E_ZJ4a1iAW5CCUCukmaj4gmSx-grpVZl15HYnfhQc7CxzbVPTQaKRoXb9SfnZZ7-AOGl2aXxYzU7DrnhXO5Si_BpkgPEaIpZY6ai6BXHdu_cj7xZ51JY9eACzsazyF-6wneC1xK0BE0eBQW-OClO996sj6sVss9gthQ2iXywBN86w046Si_I7V4WXWAignEyb2BDdSwYbl8fny3AUmRNQE_QwaC_xmm6H4KFAMatplBaiF7qSx1JP2ap8de-m-J6K5z_NfXZ4Kx_DlMzkrtw5acS2WCkkErkCQCHlRClrDhItxIQmjS-rchoidWFcJnyT2n1e5xMyXH52mU7zm8iddoLrlb9rb6harL_jYUDtZ8NXubWtH3kRt0cFy2AbZ6-P56kHIvaYf7PgpLG0EIpiKhCfnZvrgyd0AxPRHMd2SLwfKEazj-cU3NV1qaQKJUEwo-Qj4lA4062RYs9PejjorP4LfiscB5G9hAupX-dnE1hcjTZxdRQRZ9ZWgd12rvBIdIwn8-a2GZxzB0xfMyV7iXk_JsqkdffILifA)" Which indeed stats G0 V as the spectral type.

Finally Wikipedia cites Collins et al ["Transit time measurements of WASP-12b..."](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.00464.pdf) to get the temperature of 6360+130-140 K.

There is an inconsistency between the papers. Part of this may be due to WASP-12 being an evolved star and moving away from the zero age main sequence.  Also its metallicity will have an effect on its effective temperature. But part of the variation may simply be different scientists working with different data.